# Viability of tracking user logins in C++

Tags: c++, windows, windows-xp

I want to write a C++ application that collects information about user logons/logoffs for Windows XP.  I've done some searching around and have yet to find a viable way of doing this.  There doesn't appear to be a system call I could use.  I could export the log file from Event Viewer and use I/O operations but the code would be relying on the assumption that someone exported the log file.  Is it realistically possible to write a C++ application to collect information about user logons?  I'm using MinGW.

Comment: If this was possible, it sounds like a privacy issue right? Maybe with privilege elevation...

Answer (score 1):

This could be done by using an application that starts before anyone logs into the system and runs all the time, regardless of users logging in and out.  That is to say, a Windows service.

Windows services have the ability to detect and react to session changes via the `OnSessionChange` event handler.

Happy hunting!

Comment: That looks like it'll do what I what I need to do.  Thanks!

Comment: I noticed that you're targeting C++ for this.  You may find this to be an easier task using C# and .NET - just saying.  Also, please accept answer if you feel that I've answered your question.

Comment: Unfortunately the program I'm in requires all coding to be done in C/C++.  I accepted once the timer let me.

Comment: @sommerjj - Did you find a problem with the answer I supplied you for this?

Comment: Yes and no.  Your answer works, but at my current level of C++ making a service is very difficult and I don't fully grasp it.  It looked easier than it actually is.  I unchecked the answer in hopes maybe someone with a different idea would leave it.

Comment: Truly, a service is the ONLY way to have code run outside of any interactive session, and I believe that it is the ONLY way to monitor log in/out activity.  Instead of MinGW, you should seriously check out Visual Studio - building a Windows service in C# or VB.NET is pretty straightforward in that environment.  Even though you've said that it MUST be built in C/C++, the difficulty of this might make you want to question that requirement.  Cheers!